# where nothing displayed in Plot

Tags: plotting

```
r[t_] := (1/(18/ 7 - (18/7 - 1/1.1^2)*7/3*(1 + 2*3*1.1^2*(t - 16)^(1/3))))^(1/ 2); 
Plot[r[t],{t,0.1,16}]
```

I have a function and i am trying to make a Plot of it.
But nothing is being displayed, it is a totally empty graph
and no comment as an answer from Mathematica!
Is there anybody who can help me with this?

Comment: Please give the code of your function.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the function you are trying to plot and your specific call to the Wolfram Language Plot function?

Comment: You may need to use `Evaluate` or `Re` (or `Abs`) or both, e.g., `Plot[Evaluate[Re[func]], ...]`

Comment: r[t_] := (1/(18/
        7 - (18/7 - 1/1.1^2)*7/3*(1 + 2*3*1.1^2*(t - 16)^(1/3))))^(1/
     2); Plot[r[t],{t,0.1,16}]

Comment: Evaluate `r[5]` and you will see that your function is complex-valued. To `Plot` you must use real-valued function. Plot either `Re[r[t]]` or `Abs[r[t]]` or instead of `Plot` use `ReImPlot`

Answer (score 2):

A Wolfram guide is here: [Complex Visualization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ComplexVisualization.html)

Is this what you are looking for?

```
r[t_] := (1/(18/7 - (18/7 - 1/1.1^2)*7/3*(1 + 2*3*1.1^2*(t - 16)^(1/3))))^(1/2)
ReImPlot[r[x],{x,0.1,16}]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried what you suggest and it gives me as an output:

Comment: I tried what you suggest and it gives me as an output ReImPlot[.....function....] and no figure!

Comment: @IoannisSklavounos which version of Mathematica are you using?

Answer (score 1):

One way is use `Surd[t-16,3]` instead of `(t-16)^(1/3)`.

```
r[t_] := (1/(18/7 - (18/7 - 1/1.1^2)*7/3*(1 + 2*3*1.1^2*Surd[t - 16, 3])))^(1/2);
Plot[r[t], {t, 0.1, 16}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

`CubeRoot` also work.

```
r[t_] := (1/(18/7 - (18/7 - 1/1.1^2)*7/
         3*(1 + 2*3*1.1^2*CubeRoot[t - 16])))^(1/2);
Plot[r[t], {t, 0.1, 16}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Comment: Ok, it workks! Thanks!